# How to configure cssrewrite in symfony when using relative path in css in symfony 2?

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig, yaml

I've tried all the ways to do this, but still unlucky, when I view the source of my css it generates something like this `url('../../../bundles/images/bg.jpg')`

in `config.yml` I changed `use_controller` -> true same as in `config_dev.yml` this is my code `\Resources\views\layout.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %} 
{% block stylesheets %} 
{% stylesheets 'bundles/globeuser/css/bootstrap.min.css' 
    'bundles/globeuser/css/styles.css' 
    filter="cssrewrite" output="css/compiled/styles.css" %} 

<link rel="stylesheet" src="{{ asset_url }}" media="screen" /> 
{% endstylesheets %} 
{% endblock %}
```

and i used LESS to compile css
my code originally was:

```
body{
   background: url('../../images/bg.jpg');
}
```

In Resources/public/css/styles.css

I tried commands like:

```
 - php app/console assets:install web --symlink
 - php app/console assets:install
 - php app/console assetic:dump
 - php app/console assetic:dump --watch
 - php app/console cache:clear
 - php app/console assetic:watch
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the examples you tried this far? And show the directory structure.

Comment: You can edit questions. It will greatly increase readability.

Comment: sorry sir, im new to this site :)
@Kabahango

Comment: Np, thats why i'm helping.